# Cannot call class's function in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have 4 classes. When someone goes to printHi.php, it prints "hi" twice--from different classes. However:

printHi.php

```
include('main.php');
$main = new Main;
```

main.php:

```
class Main {
    function __construct() {
        include('class2.php');
        include('class3.php');
        $this->class2 = new class2;
        $this->class3 = new class3;
        $this->class2->sanity();
    }
}
```

class2.php

```
class class2 {
    public function sanity() {
        echo "Hi.";
    }
}
```

class3.php

```
class class3 {
    function __construct() {
        $this->class2 = new class2;
        $this->class2->sanity();
    }
}
```

No ouput shows (or errors)? What am I doing wrong?

Also, if I wanted to use sanity() in all of my classes, how would I do that without doing

```
$this->class2 = new class2;
$this->class2->sanity();
```

in every class?

http://pastebin.com/HHyQfvhW

Comment: add `error_reporting(0)` to the first line of your application to see errors, it looks like error reporting is of by default within the ini file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors are being thrown.  You might have [error_reporting turned off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and be seeing a blank screen, but they are being raised.  Here's a list of errors from what I can see:

- Class3's constructor is missing the `function` declaration.  This should be a fatal parse error

  ```
  function __construct() {
  ```
- Class1's constructor tries to call the method `sanity()` on the non-object `$this->class`.  This should be a fatal error.

So, obviously this isn't your actual code.  Assuming that you're just talking about making `Class2` available to all your classes, I'd suggest Dependency Injection.  So:

```
class Main {
    public function __construct(class2 $class2, Class3 $class3) {
        $this->class2 = $class2;
        $this->class3 = $class3;
        $this->class2->sanity();
    }
}
class Class2 {
    public function sanity() {...}
}
class Class3 {
    public function __construct(Class2 $class2) {
        $this->class2 = $class2;
    }
}
```

That way, everything is passed in.  It's far more flexible, easier to understand and debug, and **far** easier to test.

**Edit:** Based upon the linked code:

There are a few issues.

- Inject your dependencies.  Don't just create new instances of classes everywhere (hardcoding relationships)
- Indent your code properly.  Readability is king.  **always** indent.
- `require() or die()` is pointless.  `require` will end execution for you if it fails.  the `or die`  bit is redundent.
- The `sanity()` method on `Config` is declared as `static`, yet you're trying to call it on an instance.  Figure out if it's tied to an instance (needs to use `$this`) or not, and make it appropriately.  Then only call it appropriately.  Don't call `Foo::bar()` if bar is an instance method and vise versa.
- Your todo is wrong, since `require 'foo' or die()` is working how it should.  `OR` has the higher precidence, so that's why you get `require 1` since it's interpreted as `require ('foo' or die())`...
- Finally, don't use `require` blindly like this.  Instead, either autoload you classes, or use `require_once` in case a file was already required (to prevent errors).

Comment: this is my real code. I didn't want to put it in the original post because it's long, but some of the typos you mentioned aren't in my real code. http://pastebin.com/HHyQfvhW

Comment: @Derek: do you mind if I edit it in the original question?  It's useful and necessary to figure out what's wrong (don't worry about length)...

Answer (score 2):

You are not seeing errors likely because

```
class class3 {
    __construct() {
        $this->class2 = new class2;
        $this->class2->sanity();
    }
}
```

contains a parse error. Namely, you need to write `function __construct()`. Because of this, methods to turn on errors such as `error_reporting` and `ini_set` will not work because the script never runs due to the parse error. Therefore, look to your php.ini file and set the error_reporting and display_errors directives there. After having done that, you should see your error messages.